# None of my JS files are getting loaded on localhost

Tags: javascript, coldfusion

I installed a local coldfusion server on my computer to as a development enviroment.

I created a basepath variable (if CGI.SERVER_NAME is localhost, then set the path to `http://localhost:8500/` else set it to `http://example.com`).

For some reason none of my javascript is loading on the localhost. There is no error on the console. I look at the network and all the images and CSS are loading. I check the paths to the javascript files and they all seem to be working when I click through to them.

I'm a little lost as to what could be causing this. It is preventing me from developing on my development server.

Thank you

Edit: This the pre-processed code (inside the  tag):

```
<!---  SCRIPTS --->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#app_basepath#</cfoutput>/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#app_basepath#</cfoutput>/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#app_basepath#</cfoutput>/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#app_basepath#</cfoutput>/js/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#app_basepath#</cfoutput>/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#app_basepath#</cfoutput>/js/responsive.js"></script>
<script src="<cfoutput>#app_basepath#</cfoutput>/js/global.js"></script>
```

This is the processed code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8500/example.com/js/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8500/example.com/js/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8500/example.com/js/jquery.fancybox.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8500/example.com/js/jquery-scrolltofixed-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8500/example.com/js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8500/example.com/js/responsive.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost:8500/example.com/js/global.js"></script>
```

EDIT2: Ok, here is the code that sets the app_basepath variable

```
<cfif CGI.SERVER_NAME eq 'localhost'>
    <CFPARAM name="variables.app_basepath" default="http://localhost:8500/example.com" >
<cfelse>
     <CFPARAM name="variables.app_basepath" default="http://example.com" >
</cfif>
```

Comment: Can I see your code where you are including your js files and where you are using them?

Comment: I just added it to the top

Comment: Show us the code that sets the variable named `app_basepath`. It seems to be set to the value ' http : //localhost:8500/example.com '

Comment: Ok, I have added it above

Comment: I have to apologize. I feel like an idiot. I have a browser extension to turn javascript off and on a website. And I had it set to off.

Comment: No worries, we've all been there.

Comment: You should create an answer on how you found the root cause of the issue. It would be useful in case others run across a similar issue

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to do any of this for this need. I would suggest that you do not include the first part of the path.

Put your src like this :

```
<script src="js/jquery.customSelect.min.js"></script>
```

So this will work on your dev environnement and live as well, without changing anything on the server side.